# Message Text not Found in FEM Model

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I'm trying to solve for the heat transfer in 2D within a fluid. The geometry I'm using is a rectangle of water heated from the bottom. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
\[Rho]water = 1000;
kwater = 0.598012`;
\[Mu]water = 0.0010015961431205716`;
Cwater = 4184;
\[Alpha]water = 0.00018`;
g = 9.81;
Theat = 375;

HeatModel= {Cwater \[Rho]water D[T[x,y,t],t]+Cwater \[Rho]water u[x,y,t],Cwater \[Rho]water v[x,y,t]}. Grad[T[x, y, t],{x, y}]+Div[(-kwater Grad[T[x, y, t],{x, y}]),{x, y}];
CFDModel={\[Rho]water {u[x, y, t], v[x, y, t]} . Grad[u[x, y, t],{x, y}]+Div[(-\[Mu]water Grad[u[x, y, t],{x, y}]),{x, y}] +D[p[x,y,t],x]+D[u[x,y,t],t],\[Rho]water {u[x, y, t], v[x, y, t]} . Grad[v[x, y, t],{x, y}] + Div[(-\[Mu]water Grad[v[x, y, t],{x, y}]),{x,y}]+D[p[x,y,t],y]+D[v[x,y,t],t],D[u[x,y,t],x]+D[v[x,y,t],y]}
{Subscript[F, x], Subscript[F, y]} = {0, \[Alpha]water g \[Rho]water (T[x, y, t] - 300)};

r0 = 0.03;
h = 0.2;
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {r0, h}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], {{0, r0}, {0, h}}, "MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> 20*10^-4}];

bcbase = {DirichletCondition[T[x, y, t] == Theat, y == 0]};
bcnoslip1 =DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, t] == 0, v[x, y, t] == 0}, y == 0 || y == h];
bcpressure = DirichletCondition[p[x, y, t] == 0, y == h];
bcnoslip2 =DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, t] == 0, v[x, y, t] == 0}, x == 0 || x == r0];
ics1 = {T[x, y, 0] == 300, (D[T[x, y, t] == 0, t]) /. t -> 0};
ic2 = {u[x, y, 0] == 0, v[x, y, 0] == 0, p[x, y, 0] == 0};
bcs = {bcbase, bcnoslip1, bcpressure, bcnoslip2, ics1, ic2};

pde = {CFDModel == {Subscript[F, x], Subscript[F, y], 0}, HeatModel == 0, bcs};
solveNS =NDSolveValue[pde, {u, v, p, T}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, {t, 0, 10}, Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement","InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}}}}]
```

When the code is ran, the only error message thrown is that -- Message Text not fonud --. Interesintgly NDSolve outputs a result but the time range in the output goes from t=0s to t=0s, while the time domain provided in NDSolve is from t=0s to t=10s. Does anyone know what's wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: I can not reproduce this in V13.2. I get: LinearSolve::parpiv: Zero pivot was detected during the numerical factorization or there was a problem in the iterative refinement process. It is possible that the matrix is ill-conditioned or singular.

Comment: With this parameters it should be turbulent convection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to message `LinearSolve::parpiv: Zero pivot was detected during the numerical factorization or there was a problem in the iterative refinement process. It is possible that the matrix is ill-conditioned or singular` this problem can't be solved with using nonlinear FEM. Nevertheless we can solve it with using linear FEM as described [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064?p_p_auth=mjsAC8aX). First, we transform system to dimensionless form as follows

```
\[Rho]water = 1000;
kwater = 0.598012`;
\[Mu]water = 0.0010015961431205716`;
Cwater = 4184;
\[Alpha]water = 0.00018`;
g = 9.81;
Theat = 375; Pr0 = Cwater \[Mu]water/kwater (*7.007682559574845`*);
r0 = 0.03; u0 = kwater/r0/\[Rho]water/Cwater(* velocity scale = 4.76427660930529`*^-6*);
t0 = r0/u0 (*time scale = 6296.863608088132`*);
R = 300 \[Alpha]water g r0/u0^2 (Theat/300 - 1)(* force scale = 1.75037*10^8*);
```

With this scaling the system has a form

```
tmax = 200; Pr0 = 7.0; Ra = 1.7503709383883822`*^8/Pr0; R = 
 Ra*Pr0(*1.7503709383883822`*^8*); t0 = 6296.863608088132`; dt = 
 10^-5; a = 0; h = 20/3;
\[CapitalOmega] = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= h, {x, y}];
UX[0][x_, y_] := 0;
VY[0][x_, y_] := 0;
\[CapitalRho][0][x_, y_] := 0;
TK[0][x_, y_] := 0; TX[0][x_, y_] := 0;

Do[{UX[i], VY[i], \[CapitalRho][i], TK[i], TX[i]} = 
    NDSolveValue[{{Inactive[Div][{{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}} . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + D[p[x, y], x] + 
          UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[u[x, y], x] + VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[u[x, y], y] + (u[x, y] - UX[i - 1][x, y])/dt - R*T[x, y]*Sin[a], 
         Inactive[Div][{{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}} . Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + D[p[x, y], y] + UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[v[x, y], x] + 
          VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[v[x, y], y] - R*T[x, y]*Cos[a] + (v[x, y] - VY[i - 1][x, y])/dt, D[u[x, y], x] + D[v[x, y], y]} == {0, 0, 0} /. 
       \[Mu] -> Pr0, {DirichletCondition[{p[x, y] == 0}, y == h && x == 1], DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, y == 0 || y == h]}, 
      {UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[T[x, y], x] + VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[T[x, y], y] + (T[x, y] - TK[i - 1][x, y])/dt - 
         (D[T[x, y], x, x] + D[T[x, y], y, y]) == NeumannValue[0, x == 0 || x == 1 || y == h], DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, 
        x == 0], DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, x == 1], DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == 1, y == 0]}}, 
     {u, v, p, T, Derivative[1, 0][T]}, Element[{x, y}, \[CapitalOmega]], 
     Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}, "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}], 
   {i, 1, tmax}];
```

Note, that `tmax dt t0` is about 12.5937s while in the question `t<=10s`. Visualization

```
mesh = UX[tmax]["ElementMesh"];

Table[StreamDensityPlot[{UX[i][x, y], 
   VY[i][x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
  StreamPoints -> Fine, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t =", dt i t0}], 
  StreamColorFunction -> GrayLevel], {i, 50, 200, 50}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

```
Table[DensityPlot[TK[i][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
  PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> False, 
  PlotLabel -> i dt t0], {i, 30, 200, 10}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

This is first stage of turbulent convection. We can compute up to `tmax=400` to see this turbulent move, that we can animate as

```
lst = Table[
   DensityPlot[TK[i][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, PlotPoints -> 50, 
    ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotRange -> All, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> False], {i, 30, 400, 2}];

ListAnimate[lst]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Oh wow, thanks alot for this!!

Comment: @Lucas Yes, you are right, it looks very realistic.